# D3.js is there a way to highlight the area between 2 x-axis ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As the mouse is moving I want to be able to dynamically highlight the area between the 2 ticks that the mouse is currently positioned in.

so if my x axis is

1---2---3---4

when the mouse position is somewhere on the x-axis between 1 and 2, the whole area between 1 and 2 should be highlighted with a different color.

I haven't really seen any examples of this functionality. My guess on implementation is:

-get the distance between 2 ticks
-draw a highlight rectangle with the width set to that distance

As the mouse moves:
-find the closest ticks to current mouse position
-if closest tick is to left of mouse, position the rectangle starting at that tick
-if closest ticks is to the right, position the end of the rectangle at that tick.

I was wondering if there is already something native to D3.js that will make this any easier.

Comment: There's nothing in D3 that would make it simpler than the process you've described.